# how to setting XCode project that have two target with same bundle version

Tags: swift, xcode, build, settings, run-script

so if i upload on appstoreconnect and have different bundle version on each target it will be ignored by apple. [ignored info when uploading to appstoreconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ssw.png)

```
PLIST="${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
PLB=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
LAST_BUILD_VERSION=$($PLB -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$PLIST")
IFS=. components=($LAST_BUILD_VERSION)
major=${components[0]}
minor=${components[1]}
micro=${components[2]}
build=${components[3]}
build_plus=$((build + 1))
old_build="$major.$minor.$micro.$build"
new_build="$major.$minor.$micro.$build_plus"
$PLB -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $MARKETING_VERSION.$build_plus" "$PLIST"
```

i already made a run-script that change the last number for one target but i dont have idea to change another target using run script

if it 5.5.10.1 then it would change it to 5.5.10.2 for main target. but the other target dont get change

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think you can use User-Defined Setting at the project level, then use that value for all of your targets.

Comment: can you give step by step to use User-Defined?

Comment: @dimaskpz I updated my answer, please take a look. But why don't you use the same run-script for all other targets?

Comment: thankyou for the tutorial. the reason i dont use for another target is i dont know how to get directory to another PLIST target. cause for the main target using this variable ${INFOPLIST_FILE}. 
do you have any recomendation for my run-script? i would love to if it works using runscript only

Comment: Each target contains it own `Info.plist` file and the path for that file can be changed too. you can use `${INFOPLIST_FILE}` to get the path to the `Info.plist` file. For the run script do you know that each target can contain its own run-scripts? Adding your run-script in a particular target and use `${INFOPLIST_FILE}` will give you the correct location to the `Info.plist` of that target.

Comment: Unstable solution. Any editing in 'General' tab of version (field not disabled) breaks this binding.